# Java syntax highlighting and code suggestion stopped working for certain file

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

All out of a sudden, it stopped working, for both Eclipse Kepler and Luna.

Take a look at the following comparison:
This is the file with correct syntax highlighting and code suggestion still:
[image]
And this is the not-working one:
[image]

I have tried to use Eclipse's Help >> Check for updates but the problem persists.

I have checked the Content Assit under Preferences as suggested somewhere on StackOverflow:
[image]
Of course, I have cleaned the project, the whole workspace and restarted my Eclipse a few times.

What am I missing?

Comment: What happens if you remove all compile errors and save the file?

Comment: Absolutely nothing @DB5

Comment: hmmm, that's a shame. Okay one last thing you can try and then I'm out. Close the file, then right click on it in the explorer and explicitly select `Open With -> Java Editor`. It could be that you have some how managed to open it with a different editor.

Comment: Thanks @DB5 but that didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

I had the same or a similar issue recently. To me it seems your Java highlighting is gone, either because your JDK selection is gone, or because you have a build error.
For the first:
Try Preferences->Installed JREs (select JDK)
and or:
Preferences->Installed JREs-> Execution Environment (select a JDK on the right window).
For the second: Have a look at your build file, e.g. pom.xml for Maven, and see if something has changed in this file recently (e.g. maven compiler plugin).